# Can the C# compiler optimize this cast away?

Tags: c#

I'm doing the following cast to `double` and back to `long`, intentionally:

```
var adjustedValue = (long)(double)dateTime.Ticks;
```

(where `dateTime` is a `System.DateTime` and `Ticks` is a `long`). Resharper tells me however that the cast to `double` is "redundant" and this has me wondering if it can be optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: How does it help with `precision issue` ?

Comment: Why not compile it and look at the IL?

Comment: I call XY shenanigans.  Describe the actual problem with the precision issue you are having.

Comment: `Ticks` returns a `long`, so how could there be a "precision issue"?

Comment: The issue has to do with third-party code and is completely irrelevant; I just want to know if the cast can be optimized away.

Comment: Compile it and look at the IL.

Comment: @Sam: [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) has a precision of 19 digits.  `double` has a precision of 15 to 17 digits.  Presumably, the third-party API can only handle 15 to 17 digits of precision.

Comment: Since the precision of `double` isn't enough to hold a `long` with full precision, optimizing the cast away would change the result.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I see; of course this is all hypothetical until the OP actually clarifies.

Comment: @Sam Robert Harvey's got it right. I've edited the question to remove the bit about precision since it seems to drag the discussion off-topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried out this code in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var adjustedValue = (long)(double)dateTime.Ticks;
adjustedValue.Dump();
```

Both with and without optimizations, it generated identical IL (the only difference being in the labels):

```
IL_0000:  call        System.DateTime.get_Now
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // dateTime
IL_0006:  ldloca.s    00 // dateTime
IL_0008:  call        System.DateTime.get_Ticks
IL_000D:  conv.r8     
IL_000E:  conv.i8     
IL_000F:  stloc.1     // adjustedValue
IL_0010:  ldloc.1     // adjustedValue
IL_0011:  call        LINQPad.Extensions.Dump
```

So the answer is **no**, the C# compiler does not optimize this double cast. The conversions are there, even when optimizations are turned on.

However, you should also notice that this double-cast *does* significantly change the original data. Here's a quick demo, also created using LINQPad:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
var originalValue = dateTime.Ticks;
var adjustedValue = (long)(double)originalValue;
originalValue.Dump(); // 635385353415288655
adjustedValue.Dump(); // 635385353415288704
```

This is because a [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) only has 15-16 digits of precision, but a [`long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) may be up to 19 digits long. You're bound to get some amount of rounding error. If this is a problem, you could use a [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead. This will avoid any rounding errors, but even in this case, the double-cast will not be optimized away by the C# compiler.

Of course, how the JIT compiler or NGen.exe [convert this to native code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6.aspx) is an entirely different matter, but I would expect the behavior to be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of using LINQPad to check the IL output, that is very convenient!

Answer (score 1):

I just checked it out. With "dotPeek 1.1" I "took a look" into the source code of this.

With configuration Debug it keeps as is, because the /optimize flag is not set.
With configuration Release there is indeed something changed, but not the casts. In Release, as default, /optimize switch is turned on.

```
var adjustedValue = (long)(double)DateTime.Now.Ticks;

Console.WriteLine(adjustedValue);
```

went to

```
Console.WriteLine((long) (double) DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Résumé:

It will not optimize this way of cast.